# Changing text of initial blank option in select menu in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

I have a select menu with using ng-model and a list of values like so:

```
<select ng-model="$ctrl.ngModel"
    id = "{{$ctrl.idPrefix}}-select"
    ng-change="$ctrl.change()">
  <option ng-repeat="setting in $ctrl.values track by setting[$ctrl.valuePropertyName]"
      ng-value="setting[$ctrl.valuePropertyName]">
      {{ setting[$ctrl.textPropertyName] }}
  </option>
</select>
```

This all works well when the ng model value is in the list of $ctrl.Values. However, when it isn't I get a default option auto-inserted with a blank text which is displayed. I know I can initialize the properties value to ensure this doesn't happen. However, what I actually want to do is change the display text of this default option to something like "Please select" or similar. Is there a way to set the text which is displayed for this default option?

Answer (score 0):

you can manage this by checking if your array is empty or ngModel is null/undefined

like as sample

```
<select ng-model="$ctrl.ngModel"
    id = "{{$ctrl.idPrefix}}-select"
    ng-change="$ctrl.change()">
    <option value="" ng-if="$ctrl.values == null || $ctrl.values.length == 0 || $ctrl.ngModel == null"> Please select ... </option>
  <option ng-repeat="setting in $ctrl.values track by setting[$ctrl.valuePropertyName]"
      ng-value="setting[$ctrl.valuePropertyName]">
      {{ setting[$ctrl.textPropertyName] }}
  </option>
</select>
```